# osmdroid: calculate map size

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid.
The map is centered to a specific GeoPoint and the map has a specific zoom.
How do I calculate the map size (depending on currunt zoom-level)?
I need the GeoPoints of the upper-left and bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
mMapView.getProjection().getBoundingBox()
```

This will give you the lat/long bounding box for what is currently on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! "Found" exactly THAT function this morning...while osmdroid (osm at all) is real cool, it's "documentation" lacks...THANKS anyway, @kurtzmarc

Comment: Don't forget osmdroid follows the [Google Maps v1 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/) so use those docs too!

Answer (score 1):

And here a code snippet...

```
BoundingBoxE6 bb = mMapView.getBoundingBox();

double latFrom = bb.getLatSouthE6() / 1E6;
double latTo = bb.getLatNorthE6() / 1E6;
double lngFrom = bb.getLonWestE6() / 1E6;
double lngTo = bb.getLonEastE6() / 1E6;
```